# Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Yesterday (it's been half day already) I tried deploying a contract, but transaction is still pending, and some times instead of transaction I see "unable to locate":

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x899a9baa10fdd613886c60b602baaa88418fce165b7fcbf3c1ddea78d04c0572

Any ideas what is the reason and what to do?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/